# Why I got a dash - as the identifier after signing in via Firebase Twitter OAuth?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

My user signed up via Twitter account. But the identifier shows a `-`. It should be user's email. I checked on Twitter side, I selected `Request email address`. So email address should be collected. Why it isn't shown properly? Some bug?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because user used phone to sign up the Twitter, thus no email. It's a false alarm.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this issue? I'm facing the same problem rn.